# Unable to configure push notification for android in Titanium

Tags: android, push-notification, titanium, firebase-cloud-messaging, appcelerator-titanium

To implement push notification service in my titanium app for android, I was going through [this](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Push_Notifications/%22this%22) development document. At first, I configured push services for android device by creating a "Client ID". I saved the "Client ID" for further use, but i do not understand where this "Client ID" would be need as there is no information for this in the doc. Then I followed [this](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Subscribing_to_push_notifications/%22this%22) doc to subscribe push notification and added "ti.cloudpush" module to the tiapp.xml. But unfortunately, I'm getting error while calling retrieveDeviceToken() method. Here is my code snippet -

```
// Require the module
var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
var deviceToken = null;

// Initialize the module
CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
    success: deviceTokenSuccess,
    error: deviceTokenError
});

// Enable push notifications for this device
// Save the device token for subsequent API calls
function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
    deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
}
function deviceTokenError(e) {
    alert('Failed to register for push notifications! ' + e.error);
}

// Process incoming push notifications
CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function (evt) {
    alert("Notification received: " + evt.payload);
});
```

And here is the error I'm getting in the console -

```
Failed receiving GCM SenderId. Getting GCM SenderId failed. Max retry time reaches.
```

Note - I didn't add anything for android manifest in tiapp.xml

Answer (score 0):

When you're using Cloudpush module you will also need to configure the backend with settings. You can find how to do that in the documentation: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Configuring_push_services-section-src-37551713_Configuringpushservices-ConfiguringpushservicesforAndroiddevices

If you want to use your own backend you will need to use a different module for sending push notifications on Android. For example [ti.goosh](https://github.com/caffeinalab/ti.goosh) or [onesignal](https://github.com/williamrijksen/com.williamrijksen.onesignal)

The documentation of both modules will tell you how to configure the senderID.